# Keycloak AD FS Interaction

Tags: active-directory, saml, keycloak, adfs

I created a SAML Identity Provider in Keycloak. The single signon url is https://[URL]/adfs/ls as stated in the FederationMetadata.xml.

If I am now using the Keycloak-User-Login I see a link, where I'll be redirected to the single signon page, but after that I get an error, because I didn't specify any query parameter like `wa=signin1.0` or `whr=https:\\foo\adfs\services\trust` or `wtrealm=https:\\sso.foo.bar`

If I am including this parameters into the signle signon url correctly, I can login, but keycloak doesn't recognise what happened.

As it seems to me the URL confgured as single signon url does nothing and the Identity Provider as I have configured it in Keycloak is useless.

Can anyone help me with some pointers, to increase my understanding of the interaction between AD FS and keycloak and how they work together?

Comment: I doubt Keycloak support WS-Fed (SAML 1.0) which you apparently try by adding `wa=....`. I believe Keycloak supports SAML2 which is handled at the ADFS side by the very same endpoint (`/adfs/ls`) but with a request that conforms to the SAML2 specs. Now, ADFS supports SAML2 with two bindings, the POST binding and the REDIRECT binding. My guess is Keycloak follows the POST binding but you just haven't configured your ADFS to allow this particular binding.

Comment: To be sure, you would have to edit your question to include more details on how you configure Keycloak as the SAML2 Relying Party in ADFS.

Comment: There exists a plugin but it's not production Ready, so thx for your Input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently worked on a project where we set up KeyCloak to act as an SP to ADFS IdP.

We were only able to get the SAML requests to process correctly when the following settings were set:

---

IdP URL: `${IDP_URL}/adfs/ls/`

NameID Policy Format: `persistent`

WantAuthnRequestsSigned: `true`

WantAssertionsSigned: `true`

SignatureAlgorithm: `RSA_SHA256`

SAMLSignatureKeyName: `CERT_SUBJECT`

---

In addition to updating the NameID Policy within KeyCloak (as SP), we also had to have custom settings on the IdP side to ensure the NameID was sent back as format `persistent`.