# Only display login form if user is not connected on identity provider

Tags: keycloak, adfs

I’m new in the Keycloak’s world and I need some help to configure my login flow.

I’ve configured Keycloak to allow people to login with their ADFS account or with a ldap account.
ADFS Identity Provider is configured to use OpenID Connect.

When people connect to my application, they are redirected to Keycloak where they see a login form and a button to login through ADFS.

This work perfectly, but we would like people not to see that screen if they are already logged in on ADFS and only see the login form if they’re not connected in ADFS.

I changed the browser flow to use the Identity Provider Redirector first and then display the username password form, in this case the user is automatically logged in via ADFS, but if the user is not logged in, ADFS asks for a password and the user is not redirected to Keycloak .

Do you know how can we configure Keycloak to implement that flow?

I’m using Keycloak 11.0.0-alfresco-001 (keycloak 11 packaged by alfresco (as alfresco-identity-service) with a custom theme. The code is available on Alfresco’s github .

Here’s my browser flow configuration:

[IAM Browser flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMYkE.png)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

•   Yes, its possible to configure keycloak to implement the desired flow as a brokered IdP in the following way: -

1. While configuring ADFS in keycloak and importing its federation metadata file in it, check the settings and enable validate the signature option for the authentication requests to be sent to ADFS, also enable ‘Want AuthnRequests’ signed option. Afterwards, set the signature key name field to CERT_SUBJECT as AD FS expects the signing key name hint to be the subject of the signing certificate.
2. Then check the mappers for group and attribute claims in keycloak for transforming the details through SAML assertion to keycloak user store.
3. After that, check the descriptor URI that needs to be set by modifying the ADFS redirect URI by adding the ‘/descriptor’ to the redirect URI in this field. The URI will be like ‘https://kc.domain.name:8443/auth/realms/master/broker/adfs-idp-alias/endpoint/descriptor’.
4. Also, please ensure that the signing certificate for the keycloak in ADFS claims provider is not self-signed and is issued from a trusted third-party CA and installed in the server’s local system certificate store.
5. Disable certificate revocation check for the certificate installed on the Adfs server and ensure ‘backchannel logout’ option is checked in keycloak

•   Once the above settings are checked thoroughly, the default login redirection page should be displayed after that and the user should be able to select the IdP from the login page accordingly.

Please find the below links for more information: -

https://www.keycloak.org/2017/03/how-to-setup-ms-ad-fs-30-as-brokered.html

[Keycloak AD FS Interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56632314/keycloak-ad-fs-interaction)